# How match multiple character and insert in new line

Tags: bash, sed

I want match the string and start with new line. In below text I want to match date  "06/18/2021"

```
06/18/2021 06:01:46 - Info for client my.com, 06/18/2021 06:01:47 schedule 06/18/2021 06:01:48 - Info requesting resources
```

expected text:

```
06/18/2021 06:01:46 - Info for client my.com,
06/18/2021 06:01:47 schedule
06/18/2021 06:01:48 - Info requesting resources
```

I tried to sed command but it giving me below output. In same line date and time have 06.

```
cat  | sed 's/06/\n&/g'
```

```
06/18/2021 
06:01:46 - Info for client my.com,
06/18/2021 
06:01:47 schedule
06/18/2021 
06:01:48 - Info requesting resources
```

Comment: Thanks Jetchisel for reformatting the content.

Comment: You should match the `/` after `06`, so it doesn't match `06:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the `/` in the pattern so it only matches `06/`, not `06:`

```
sed 's#06/#\n&#g'
```

A better idea would be to use a pattern that matches the entire date, so it's not specific to a particular month. Also `06/` will put a newline in the middle of `06/06/2021`.

```
sed 's#[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]#\n&#g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT to match just the exact date you asked for, `06/18/2021`:

```
$ awk -v RS='06/18/2021|\n' 'NR>1{print pRT $0} {pRT=RT}' file
06/18/2021 06:01:46 - Info for client my.com,
06/18/2021 06:01:47 schedule
06/18/2021 06:01:48 - Info requesting resources
```

or to match any date in that `MM/DD/YYYY` format:

```
$ awk -v RS='([0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4}|\n' 'NR>1{print pRT $0} {pRT=RT}' file
06/18/2021 06:01:46 - Info for client my.com,
06/18/2021 06:01:47 schedule
06/18/2021 06:01:48 - Info requesting resources
```

or, more robustly, to match on date+time:

```
$ awk -v RS='([0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}|\n' 'NR>1{print pRT $0} {pRT=RT}' file
06/18/2021 06:01:46 - Info for client my.com,
06/18/2021 06:01:47 schedule
06/18/2021 06:01:48 - Info requesting resources
```